# Creating vs Modifying in backbone.js

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

This is my first application using backbone and REST API, I'm a bit confused with some specific scenarios when it comes to creating-editing. So if the model exits on server, it will EDIT, if it doesn't it CREATES.

When I pass on a unique identifier in my model, it knows it exits, but if I pass a combination of existing data without a unique identifier it always assumes it should CREATE. I'm not sure if this should be solved on client side or server.

For instance:

```
var exportationMod = new Backbone.Model({ 'asset': '/api/v1/asset/'+this.assetID+'/', 'export_configuration': '/api/v1/exportconfiguration/'+this.model.get('id')+'/' });
exportationMod.url = '/api/v1/exportation/';
exportationMod.save();
```

OK so the server is running with django + tastypie. Should this be validated by the client by first making an extra query, on the server (maybe there is a way of setting a combination of unique keys like mysql), or is there another setting I can tweak so it edits instead of creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass data to the server without some unique id, how would the server know what to update?

If it makes sense for your situation, you can override `isNew()` in your model.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: 'somethingUnique',
   url: '/api/v1/exportation/',
   isNew: function(){
      // return true if you want create (POST),
      // return false if you want update (PUT)
   }
});
```

By default it looks like this (with the above model, this.id would be the idAttribute value above):

```
// A model is new if it has never been saved to the server, and lacks an id.
isNew: function() {
  return this.id == null;
},
```

If you want to edit something that already exists on the server, you should just fetch it first before editing/saving it.  Also, if there is some unique id that is not called 'id' you can override that on the model as well (see above).